# Linker error with a xbox 360 controller function

Tags: c++, controller, xbox

I'm getting an undefined reference for `XInputGetState` and I have no idea why.
The headers I'm using are : `XInput.h` and `Windows.h`.

`FIRSTPLAYER` is just the constant `0`.

```
XINPUT_STATE state;
ZeroMemory( &state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE) );
// Simply get the state of the controller from XInput.
dwResult = XInputGetState( FIRSTPLAYER, &state );
```

Any advice would be nice.

I'm using CodeBlocks IDE with MinGW as a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I figured it out.
Was missing this line :

```
#pragma comment(lib, "XInput.lib")
```

is there a better work around for this? I feel like this is strange!